# Running armhf guest on amd64 host

Tags: gcc, arm, virtual-machine, virtualbox, cross-compiling

I want to develop a rather complex Linux app (using gcc/g++). At first I tried to compile it on my target hardware (Orange Pi Zero) and while the source code was small, it could barely compile it. Now that I added more libraries and stuff it is painstakingly slow and miserable.

My immediate solution was to find some toolchain  to run on my Desktop PC (Windows 10 with Ubunutu 20.04 as WSL using Linaro arm-gcc-noneeabihf). I managed to do crosscompile (code is on Windows, tooclahin is in WSL) and remote debug using gdbserver. But this is becoming too much hassle...

I want to find a way to emulate the target operation system (Armbian) and use the full power of my i9 Desktop PC to do compile stuff and do not waste time fixing library paths and stuff on Linaro toolchain.

Is there any hope for what I wish to have?

Answer (score 0):

The usual answer to “how can I emulate X on Y is qemu, available on Windows and Ubuntu. Note that it may actually be easier and faster to deploy and do remote debugging. https://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/ May be helpful.